# find the length of the longest chain of characters in each row of a dataframe

Tags: r

I want to find the length of the longest chain of characters following a pattern. Let's say I have this dataframe, and I want to find the length of rows were the sequence "a" is repeating how do i find it?

```
id = c(1, 2, 3,4,5)
A = c("a","a","a","a","a")
B = c("a","a","b","a","d")
C = c("b","a","c","a","a")
D = c("a","a","a","b","c")
E = c("a","a","e","c","a")

df = data.frame(id,A,B,C,D,E,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$Count = c(2,5,1,3,1)

  id A B C D E Count
  1 a a b a a     2
  2 a a a a a     5
  3 a b c a e     1
  4 a a a b c     3
  5 a d a c a     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rle` (*run-length encoding*).

```
    rles = apply(df[2:6], 1, rle)
    result = sapply(rles, function(x) max(x$lengths[x$values == "a"]))
    df$new_count = result
    df
    #   id A B C D E Count new_count
    # 1  1 a a b a a     2         2
    # 2  2 a a a a a     5         5
    # 3  3 a b c a e     1         1
    # 4  4 a a a b c     3         3
    # 5  5 a d a c a     1         1
```

See `?rle` or many other questions on this site if you search for "[r] rle" for additional details.

Comment: It worked, I didn't expected my list to be that heavy (140 Mb). Thanks